# argparse in Python

Tags: python, argparse

I came across this Python script:

```
parser = ap.ArgumentParser() 
parser.add_argument("-t", "--trainingSet", help="Path to Training Set", required="True")
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
train_path = args["trainingSet"]
```

The points I didn't get are:

- How do we use those arguments in the command line: "-t", "--trainingSet", help="Path to Training Set", required="True"?
- What does `args` mean? How was the training path retrieved?

Thanks.

Comment: `args` means "arguments", and you run the program like `python script.py -t something`... Does that help?

Comment: have you looked at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)?  It explains a lot about how it works.

Comment: You could use both `-t` and `--trainingSet`. Also, you should provide boolean `True` for `required` argument of `add_argument`.

Comment: maybe the part you are confused about is that [`add_argument`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument) only adds one argument, there is no argument called [`required`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required) that just means that the `--trainingSet` argument is required

Answer (score 1):

Create a `parser` object:

```
parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
```

add an argument definition to the parser (it creates an `Action` object, though you don't need to worry about that here).

```
parser.add_argument("-t", "--trainingSet", help="Path to Training Set", required="True")
```

Tell the `parser` to parse the commandline arguments that are available in `sys.argv`.  This a list of strings created by the commandline shell (bash or dos).

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

`args` is a `argparse.Namespace` object.  It is a simple object class.  `vars` converts it to a dictionary

```
argdict = vars(args)
```

This is ordinary dictionary access

```
train_path = argdict["trainingSet"]
```

you can get the same thing from the namespace

```
train_path = args.trainingSet
```

I'd recommend looking at `args`

```
print args
```

With this `parser` definition, a commandline like

```
$ python myprog.py -t astring    # or
$ python myprog.py --trainingSet anotherstring
```

will end up setting `train_path` to the respective string value. It is up to the rest of your code to use that value.

The `help` parameter will show up in the help message, such as when you do

```
$ python myprog.py -h
```

The `required` parameter means that the `parser` will raise an error if you don't provide this argument, e.g.

```
$ python myprog.py
```